# Utilizar o if para rodar uma consulta

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, pl-sql

Eu fiz uma query que busca o endereço de um cliente que utiliza um "sistema" legado, e tem a sua tabela de endereço como legado. Porem eu gostaria de fazer uma consulta que me traga o endereço  de clientes caso não seja legado e faria a consulta em uma outra tabela mais nova de endereço.

Algo tipo assim (CONSULTA FICTÍCIA)

```
Select 
L.Sistema
If (L.sistema = 'legado', select R.endereco from cadastro R,

Select N.endereco from cadastro N) as 'endereço'
From cadastro R
JOIN CADASTRO N ON L.ID = N.ID
```

Na verdade eu não  sei ao certo se é  possível utilizar  o if para executar uma consulta caso a expressão  seja verdadeira e executar outra consulta em outras tabela caso seja falso

Comment: Parece ser uma ação que se encaixa bem na  cláusula **CASE**

Comment: MySQL é o sistema atual e Oracle sistema legado ou contrário Oracle é o sistema atual e MySQL é o sistema legado? Já foi considerada a migração dos dados? Esse campo `L.sistema = 'legado'` existe ou é um campo fictício que deseja implementar?

Comment: Ambos são  oracle, porem os dados de endereço  ficam em tabelas diferentes devido a questão  de siatema do usuário

Answer (score -3):

É possível sim! Criei uma função que demonstra a criação de um comando condicional em SQL. Nesta demonstração não existe uma relação entre a tabela cliente e endereço, logo, não exercendo a função que você pediu! Porém, é possível uma QUERY de Select com comando if.

```
CREATE FUNCTION func() RETURNS boolean
AS
$$
BEGIN
    SELECT tipo_sistema FROM clientes;
    IF (tipo_sistema LIKE 'legado') THEN
        SELECT * FROM endereco;
        RETURN true;
    ELSE
        RETURN false;
    END IF
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

[Link de referencia sobre o assunto em PostgresSQL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Rx6chu6lTM&ab_channel=DesCOMPlica%2COliba%21)

Comment: Comentário do Autor da pergunta: *Sou Iniciante na programação e vi sua dúvida como um desafio, qualquer feedback para melhoria é bem vinda!*

Comment: PL/pgSQL é diferente de PL/SQL. Uma é a extensão PostgresSQL ao SQL a outra é extensão Oracle ao SQL. Se olhar as tags da pergunta verá que a pergunta é sobre MySQL e Oracle.

Comment: Sim, apenas utilizei o Postgres por ser o único banco acessível para mim! Porém, minhas pesquisas foram baseadas em SQL com algumas adaptações ao Postgres. Acredito que o fundamento da pergunta, se é possível criar um IF no SQL tenha sido respondida com êxito.